# Induction of $\sum_{k=1}^n(2k-1)^2 = \frac{1}{3}n (2n-1)(2n+1), n \geq 1$

Tags: analysis, induction

I want to understand the induction proof of

$$\sum_{k=1}^n(2k-1)^2 = \frac{1}{3}n (2n-1)(2n+1), n \geq 1$$

Here's the induction steps:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(2k-1)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n(2k-1)^2 + (2(n+1)-1)^2$$

$$= \frac{1}{3}n (2n-1)(2n+1)+(2n+2-1)^2$$

$$=\frac{1}{3}(2n+1)(n(2n-1)+3\cdot(2n+1))$$

$$=\frac{1}{3} (2n+1)(2n^2+5n+3)$$

$$=\frac{1}{3}(2n+1)(2n+3)(n+1)$$

What I don't understand is how you get from 
$$= \frac{1}{3}n (2n-1)(2n+1)+(2n+2-1)^2$$

to

$$=\frac{1}{3}(2n+1)(n(2n-1)+3\cdot(2n+1))$$

Comment: **Note :** $(2n+2-1) = (2n+1)$ . Now take common and simplify

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit I know that $2-1 = 1$. That doesn't help me though. $(2n+1)^2 = 4n^2+4n+1$.  But we have $3 \cdot (2n+1)$ above. That's what I don't get.

Comment: Its factored out. The parantheses are different! See the answer of @user to get the full details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

$$\ldots= \frac{1}{3}n (2n-1)(2n+1)+(2n+2-1)^2=\frac{1}{3}n (2n-1)(2n+1)+(2n+1)^2=$$

$$=\frac{1}{3}(2n+1)\cdot\left[n (2n-1)+3(2n+1)\right]=\ldots$$

which is obtained factoring out the $\frac{1}{3}(2n+1)$ term.